# SCplugin stop working after upgrading the mac to OSx Yosemite

Tags: ios, iphone, operating-system, osx-mountain-lion, osx-yosemite

SCplugin stop working after upgrading the mac to OSx Yosemite .However it was working on previous version.

Comment: years later, still no solution or alternative ...

Answer (score -1):

well you can try this i have heard it works on Yosemite too.

http://tripletwollc.com/2014/01/using-scplugins-sctoolbarbutton-with-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/